# Adding bg images to child divs within a table

Tags: html, css

I have a table that contains 3 divs as follows:

```
<table class="launcherGrid">
<tbody>
    <tr rowindex="0">
        <td>
            <div class="app-launch ">
                <i class="fa-launch fa-app"></i>aaa <span class="app-version">
                    v0</span> <span class="app-description">111</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr rowindex="1">
        <td>
            <div class="app-launch ">
                <i class="fa-launch fa-app"></i>bbb <span class="app-version">
                    v0</span> <span class="app-description">222</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr rowindex="2">
        <td>
            <div class="app-launch ">
                <i class="fa-launch fa-app"></i>ccc <span class="app-version">
                    v0</span> <span class="app-description">333</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am trying to apply a different background image to each div via css, i can not modify the source code.

I have tried to pinpoint each one using:

```
.launcherGrid div:nth-child(2) {
    background: url(../img/icon-admin.png) right no-repeat;
}
```

but this modofies all divs. Any suggestion on how this can be done in only css.

Comment: I am not sure how that css is selecting all the `div`s, because the `div`s are not directly related children. This is what you need. `.launcherGrid tr:nth-child(2) div {background: url(../img/icon-admin.png) right no-repeat;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target the `<tr>` nth-child then your app-launch class and it should work. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cey8k111/)

```css
.launcherGrid tr:nth-child(1) div.app-launch {
    background: url('https://placehold.it/250x100') right no-repeat;
    height: 100px;
}

.launcherGrid tr:nth-child(2) div.app-launch {
    background: url('https://placehold.it/225x70') right no-repeat;
    height: 70px;
}

.launcherGrid tr:nth-child(3) div.app-launch {
    background: url('https://placehold.it/200x50') right no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table class="launcherGrid"> 
<tbody> 
<tr rowindex="0"> 
<td> 
<div class="app-launch ">
<i class="fa-launch fa-app"></i>aaa 
<span class="app-version"> v0</span> 
<span class="app-description">111</span> </div>
</td> 
</tr>
<tr rowindex="1"> 
<td> 
<div class="app-launch ">
<i class="fa-launch fa-app"></i>bbb
<span class="app-version"> v0</span> 
<span class="app-description">222</span> 
</div> 
</td> 
</tr>
<tr rowindex="2"> 
<td> 
<div class="app-launch ">
<i class="fa-launch fa-app"></i>ccc 
<span class="app-version"> v0</span> 
<span class="app-description">333</span> 
</div> 
</td> 
</tr>
</tbody> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

:nth of type works based off the parent element.

You css wasn't working because there is only one div for each td.

try

```
.launcherGrid tr:nth-of-type(1){
   background: url(../img/icon-admin.png) right no-repeat;
}
```

instead.  That will allow you to target individual rows of your table.